# Filter order collection by discount

Tags: magento-1.7, orders, filter

How can we filter orders who have discounts?

```
$order_collection = Mage::getModel('sales/order')
->getCollection()
->addAttributeToSelect('*')
->addAttributeToFilter('discount_or_something_else', array('gt' => 0));
```

Its not working.

Answer (score 1):

You should filter on *`base_discount_amount`* and you should use *`addFieldToFilter`* instead of *`addAttributeToFilter`*.

Try changing your code with this:

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->getCollection();
$collection->addFieldToFilter('base_discount_amount', array('gt' => 0));
```

Hope it helps